# transition does not apply on scroll bar?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

In Webkit browsers it is possible to style the scrollbar with CSS:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #EEE;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #AAA;
}
```

However, it seems like `-webkit-transition` does not apply when I hover on the scroll bar piece. Is it supposed to behave like this or there is some error in [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/t5r4r/)?

Comment: @Boaz - It was asked 2 years ago, and probably they have fixed it already.

Comment: I don't think there is an error - I am on Chrome 25, and the transition property still doesn't work on the scrollbar :(

Comment: You have virtually the same exact code. Guess you should necromance that question.

Comment: And I'm not sure whether this can be considered a bug. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property) states "Applies to:  all elements, :before and :after pseudo elements", it doesn't say a word about shadow DOM.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - You can also say [`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background) applies to all elements except pseudo elements, but clearly it does apply to scroll bars.

Comment: The spec is rather ambiguous then. And the bug is not fixed yet https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104412

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Seems like they aren't going to fix it any time soon. :(

Comment: Well I don't know, the `::before` and `::after` transitions were fixed quite recently, so there's still hope. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo selectors don't implement CSS3 transitions, yet.

Comment: To be pedantic: generated content (`::before`, `::after`) will respect `transition: inherit`, allowing the author to specify the desired properties on the parent element — but this is no help for the OP's situation.